# Is there any way in matplotlib to make a dashed line when i have too many points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a figure of some data and some limits as dashed lines.
The problem i have is that the values of limits are way too many and some
are repeated on the x-axis so what i get is something like a solid line.
I would like to ask you if there is any way to actually produce dashed line.
Thank you

My code is as follow and the image i produce

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
fig.set_size_inches(4, 2.36, forward=True)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.scatter('SZA [deg]','SWD [W/m**2]', data = QC,
              marker='o',color = 'k',s=0.1)
plt.plot('SZA [deg]','GLBMaxPhys', data = QC, 
         linestyle='--',color = 'r',linewidth = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: reduce input data for `data = QC`, let say take every 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one potential solution:

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
fig.set_size_inches(4, 2.36, forward=True)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.scatter('SZA [deg]','SWD [W/m**2]', data = QC,
              marker='o',color = 'k',s=0.1)
plt.plot('SZA [deg]','GLBMaxPhys', data = QC[::50], ##change this number  
         linestyle='--',color = 'r',linewidth = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `markevery` option in the plot call.

```
plt.plot(..., marker='o', markevery=5, ...)
```

This will only mark every 5th point.

You can check the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markevery).